# WCF service with authentication using BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, basichttpbinding, wcftestclient

As per this link
http://www.brhlavinka.com/2013/06/07/secure-wcf-service-with-basichttpbinding-and-custom-credentials/

I implemented a WCF service with authentication using BasicHttpBinding. All works fine but have few questions.

1. How can I test this service from WCFTestCleint ?. I get error as "The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.".
2. We need to provide this API over internet ....would it be possible to access this kind of WCF from any programming language ?.

Comment: 1. WCFTestClient cannot handle customized WCF services that require authentication; it just allows you to test the basic functionality. 2. Yes.  You're using `BasicHttpBinding`, which is SOAP 1.1, so as long as the client is communicating with SOAP 1.1 and properly authenticates itself, it can be written in any language.  That's the whole idea behind web services, which WCF is (as well as a replacement for .NET Remoting).

Comment: @Tim I recommend re-posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Testing WCF Service I recommend you use [SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org/) it works with any authentication type